# WCF self-hosted SSL not really SSL

Tags: ssl

We have a WCF Self hosted application that uses SSL but we have it on port 15014.  I when through and did everything that MSDN lists for attaching the SSL cert to the port and the code.  It works when i browse to 'https://secure.mydomain.com:15014'.  The issue is when i look at that connection through wireshark i only see tcp as the protocol and not SSLv?.  I don't see any client handshake at all.  This leads me to believe that it is not really secure.  Am i correct on this?

Comment: Do you see plaintext HTTP GET requests? And responses?